# Way-points - How can i remove a specific way-point from google maps?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am making this app with the help of google maps, i am successfully adding `waypoints` in a route and making a route between them. But on `dbclick` i remove that way point from the map. Now when i make the route it includes the deleted `waypoint` too. Because of the fact it does not delete from the `waypoint` array.

The question is how can i remove a specific `waypoint` from the waypoint array. I dont have any `index` of something.

**pushing waypoints**

```
/* Whenever a user taps a pin it goes into pinwapypts */
        pinwaypts.push({
          location: $scope.destination_route,
          stopover: true,

        });
```

**Add waypoints in map**

```
 infowindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        $scope.markers.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          infowindow.setContent($scope.results[0].formatted_address);
          infowindow.open($scope.map, this);
        });
```

**removing waypoint marker from map**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function () {
          $scope.markers.pop().setMap(null);

        });
```

Now how can i remove a specific `waypoint` from its array ?

**full code**

```
  function getClickLoc(latlng) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'location': latlng
  }, function (results, status) {
    $scope.results = results;
    //console.log(results);
    if (status === 'OK') {
      if (results[0]) {
        $scope.map.setZoom(12);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: $scope.map
        });


        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);

        $scope.destination_route = latlng;

        /* Whenever a user taps a pin it goes into pinwapypts */
        pinwaypts.push({
          location: latlng,
          stopover: true

        });

        $scope.$apply();

        infowindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        $scope.markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function () {
          infowindow.setContent($scope.results[0].formatted_address);
          infowindow.open($scope.map, this);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function () {
          $scope.markers.pop().setMap(null);
        });

        //$ionicLoading.hide();
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Something went wrong, Please try again.');
      //window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Before you get your route, for every waypoint you add there is one corresponding marker in the same order?

Comment: please see my full code

Answer (score 0):

Your full code has a lot of missing things, so I gave a best-effort to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example out of it. This assumes you create a waypoint each time you create a marker. And markers are created via click/tap on the map.

When removing a waypoint from an array, you can get its index using `indexOf`. So inside your listener for `dblclick`, you get the index by doing:

```
var wayptIndex = $scope.pinwaypts.indexOf(waypoint);
```

and then splicing it by:

```
$scope.pinwaypts.splice(wayptIndex, 1);
```

I provided the example code below (Be sure to use your own API KEY) and you'll notice the listener is in a closure. This is so that I can still pass the `waypoint` variable to it, without it losing scope.

You can also check this [jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/lomohac/edit?js,output)

P.S.
Your removal of markers is also incorrect. Do not do a `pop()` as that only removes the last item in the array. If you double click a middle array, it will still remove the last item. I also used `indexOf` to get the marker's correct index.

Hope this helps and hope you can create minimal and complete examples next time! :)

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('ngApp', [])
    .controller('demoController', demoController);

  function demoController($scope) {
    initMap();
    $scope.pinwaypts = [];
    $scope.markers = [];

    function initMap() {
      $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: -34.397,
          lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
      });


      $scope.map.addListener('click', getClickLoc);
    }


    function getClickLoc(e) {
      var latlng = e.latLng;
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode({
        'location': latlng
      }, function(results, status) {
        $scope.results = results;
        if (status === 'OK') {
          if (results[0]) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlng,
              map: $scope.map
            });
            $scope.map.panTo(latlng);
            $scope.map.setZoom(12);

            // you did not show how you instantiated your infowindow so I added this
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
            $scope.markers.push(marker);
            $scope.destination_route = latlng;

            /* Whenever a user taps a pin it goes into pinwapypts */
            var waypoint = {
              location: latlng,
              stopover: true
            };
            $scope.pinwaypts.push(waypoint);

            // I'm not sure if you still really need this.
            $scope.$apply();

            infowindow.open($scope.map, marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              // This is redundant. You can just open the infowindow on click of the marker                   // infowindow.setContent($scope.results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open($scope.map, this);
            });

            (function(waypoint, marker) {
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function() {
              // Pop has an issue. You will only remove the last marker from your array, 
              // not the specific marker the user is double-clicking. 
              // $scope.markers.pop().setMap(null);
                var markerIndex = $scope.markers.indexOf(marker);
              // You don't remove the markers from the array. Just set them to setMap(null)
       // removing them will mess up their indeces and this will no long work
       // just refresh the markers array on a new request or something
                $scope.markers[markerIndex].setMap(null);
              // Get the index of the waypoint and this once you remove so that 
              // it's not included when you do a directions service request
                var wayptIndex = $scope.pinwaypts.indexOf(waypoint);
                $scope.pinwaypts.splice(wayptIndex, 1);
              });
            }(waypoint, marker))

          } else {
            window.alert('No results found');
          }
        } else {
          window.alert('Something went wrong, Please try again.');
        }
      });
    }
  }
})(window.angular);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body,
#view {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <!-- BE SURE TO USE YOUR OWN API KEY. This loads the script synchronously and I call initMap manually inside my controller. For demo purposes only. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAZVylT7o5OxdosVfh-IVONHoaA0cpN5VI"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ngApp">
  <div id="view" ng-controller="demoController">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```